# iOS core animation skip few seconds

Tags: objective-c, core-graphics, quartz-core, caanimation

I'm creating an animating app that takes 70 seconds and it will load again from the 2 seconds of the initial iteration. Is there a way to skip or navigate the CAAnimation ?

Comment: So the animation time goes like: 0, 1, 2, 3, ..., 69, 70, 2, 3, ..., 69, 70, 2, 3, ... ?

Comment: Exactly. Likewise I need to do more than 70 animations since they all are in a sequence

Answer (score 3):

You could use **setBeginTime**:

```
[yourAnimation setBeginTime:CACurrentMediaTime()+2.0];
```

You just need to create first animation and add the code above for two second delay to the second animation.

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't work up.. I'm using NSTimer and calling the animating function again. In the second cycle, I'm using different delays with repeat.

Comment: The answer tells you how you can add some delay to the animation. You can adjust the logic you have to make it work. There are plenty of way you can accomplish it for example you can create variable which store delay and in the second cycle you can adjust it to the required value and pass it to the function which set up the beginTime for you.

Comment: This code does create delay for the specific animation. But, I want to skip the keyframes of the animation. For example, if the stroke fill starts from 0 to 1 from time 30 to 35.3, I need to skip directly to 33.2 state.

Comment: Just keep current value of the stroke and in the next animation continue from that. PS. Your question is about skipping the animation, no keyframes.